# PDF stream getting uploaded to gdrive instead of pdf while using gdrive API v3

Tags: python, google-drive-api

When uplaoding to gdrive using python drf, the inmemoryfile get's uploaded like this (images attached below). I have been on this for a week now and still haven't found a solution. Kindly help me. THank you!

**This is the function that uploads the file**

```
def add_file(file, parent_folder_id):
file_name = "certificate.pdf"

file_metadata = {
    "name": file_name,
    "mimeType": "application/pdf", # Mimetype for docx
    'parents': [parent_folder_id]
}

media = MediaIoBaseUpload(io.BytesIO(file.read()), # **Pass your bytes object/string here
                          mimetype="application/pdf", # I'm converting docx to native google docs
                          resumable=True)


file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields="id, name").execute()

print("Uploaded File '{}' with ID: {}".format(file.get("name"), file.get("id")))
```

**This is the view in drf that gets the pdf**

```
class DetailsView(APIView):
parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

def post(self, request, format=None):
    key_req = ["name", "sap", "age", "gender", "department", "year", "file"]
    for i in list(request.data.keys()):
        if i not in key_req:
            return Response({"data" : {"val":False, "detail":"Invalid request parameters"}}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    file = request.FILES["file"]

    name = request.data["name"]
    sap = request.data["sap"]
    age = request.data["age"]
    gender = request.data["gender"]
    dep = request.data["department"]
    year = request.data["year"]

    d = {}
    d["file"] = request.data["file"]
    serializer = FileSerializer(data=d)
    if serializer.is_valid():

        verified = verify.verify(request.data["file"])
        if verified["val"] == False:
            return Response({"data" : {"val":verified["val"], "detail" : verified["details"]}}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        
        #save all data to model
        s = drive.add_folder(sap, dep, year)
        drive.add_file(file, s["id"])

        return Response({"data" : {"val":True, "detail" : "Success"}}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response({"data" : {"val" : False, "detail" : serializer.errors}}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**The uploaded file looks like**
[image]
**When viewed in google docs**
[image]

Comment: You are uploading an image? yet you set the mime type to a pdf? "mimeType": "application/pdf", # Mimetype for docx   This is the google docs mime type application/vnd.google-apps.document

Comment: From what I understand from your question, it looks like you are trying to upload a PDF file after submitting a form in Django Framework. The first thing that should be checked is if the file is well formed. To do this you could try to save it and view the file. I leave you a [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) to the documentation where it teaches you how to do it.